# How to create a new node under the last node?

Tags: xml, vbscript

```
     <TestSuite Desc="ADI [UK]">
    <TestCase TcName=" Testing" >
      <Step ID="Step 1" Desc=" ">
        <StepDetails Status="4"  StepType="Step">Step 1 Info </StepDetails>
        <StepHeader StepType="STEPHEADER" Status="2">
          <StepDetails StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 1 Info </StepDetails>
          <StepDetails Status="3" StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 1 Warning </StepDetails>
          <StepHeader>
            <StepDetails Status="4"StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 Info </StepDetails>
          </StepHeader>
        </StepHeader>
      </Step>
    </TestCase>
  </TestSuite>
```

how to create a function to get the last "StepHeader" node as a object and when i call the function a new "StepHeader" node created under the last "stepHeader" to be like this

```
  <TestSuite Desc="ADI [UK]">
    <TestCase TcName=" Testing" >
      <Step ID="Step 1" Desc=" ">
        <StepDetails Status="4"  StepType="Step">Step 1 Info </StepDetails>
        <StepHeader StepType="STEPHEADER" Status="2">
          <StepDetails StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 1 Info </StepDetails>
          <StepDetails Status="3" StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 1 Warning </StepDetails>
          <StepHeader>
            <StepDetails Status="4"StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 Info </StepDetails>
              <StepHeader>
                <StepDetails Status="4"StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 Info </StepDetails>
              </StepHeader>
          </StepHeader>
        </StepHeader>
      </Step>
    </TestCase>
  </TestSuite>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `XMLDOM` class can do everything you need. First, load your XML document.

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")  
xmlDoc.Load "c:\test.xml"
```

Then use `selectSingleNode()` to grab the parent of the node you'd like to insert.

```
Set objRoot = xmlDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("/TestSuite/TestCase/Step/StepHeader/StepHeader")
```

Next, create and append your `StepHeader` node under the node found above.

```
Set objNode = xmlDoc.createElement("StepHeader")
objRoot.appendChild objNode
```

And add the `StepDetails` sub-node (with text) and append it to the `StepHeader` node.

```
Set objSub = xmlDoc.createElement("StepDetails")
objSub.Text = "Step Header 2 Info"
objNode.appendChild objSub
```

Finally, save the new XML document.

```
xmlDoc.Save "c:\test.xml"
```

It should be noted that your original XML document has a small error.

```
<StepDetails Status="4"StepType=...    ' Need a space
<StepDetails Status="4" StepType=...   ' So that it looks like this
```

Comment: thanks for the replay but do you have any idea how to do this using "XMLUtil" object not "Microsoft.XMLDOM"

Comment: I don't, no. I believe `XMLUtil` is a Java class. You had this question tagged as `VBScript` so I used the `XMLDOM` COM object via VBScript.